# How to test Native Ad if no ad loads in the testflight version

Tags: ios, swift, testing, swiftui, admob

I have uploaded my app to the Testflight. But this does not load native ad with the real native ad id but the other ads are working fine and getting loaded successfully. Now is there any way to test the native ad to the testflight version?

Comment: Are Ads showing with Test Ad ID? If yes then your integration is completely perfect Sometimes you should wait some with the newly created account check this, 

https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/PKwFfoMh0pA?pli=1